# How to remove the brace around the reference item

Tags: citing

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
IG, suggested by  \cite{A2016} 

\begin{thebibliography}{18}
\bibitem[A (2016)]{A2016}
S. A. xxxxx. Springer, ny, 2016.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It always show "IG, suggested by [A (2016)]" , how to remove []?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you replace the directive `\bibliographystyle{plain}` with `\usepackage[round]{natbib}` (and delete the whitespace between the author name and the year in the optional argument of `\bibitem`).

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\dots\ IG, suggested by \cite{A2016} 

\begin{thebibliography}{18}

\bibitem[Author(2016)]{A2016}
Sam Author xxxxx. Springer, ny, 2016.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `cite` package allows to conveniently modify the delimiters:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[biblabel]{cite}
\renewcommand{\citeleft}{}
\renewcommand{\citeright}{}

\begin{document}
IG, suggested by  \cite{A2016} 

\begin{thebibliography}{18}
\bibitem[A (2016)]{A2016}
S. A. xxxxx. Springer, ny, 2016.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, how to remove the following second [] in References? I mean just show "A (2016). S. A. xxxxx. Springer, ny, 2016."

Comment: @Fred Please see my edit